# How is a struct with Vec<i32> and Option<i32> stored in memory?

Tags: rust, memory, memory-management

Within a program, the following data structure is defined:

```
struct Bucket {
    data: Vec<i32>,
    threshold: Option<i32>,
}
```

Using the debugger, it has been determined that, for an instance of `Bucket`, it is stored at the address 0x00006000014ed2c0. Observing the memory at this address, the following content is shown (in blocks of 32 bits):

```
308a6e01 00600000 03000000 00000000 03000000 00000000 01000000 0a000000
```

What can be inferred about the values contained in the various fields of the individual instance?

I figured out that the first 24 bytes are the pointer to the first `i32` element, the capacity, and the length. I do not understand the rest of the blocks.

Comment: You should add the code that lead to these observed values.

Answer (score 2):

Rust only rarely makes guaranties about how things are laid out in memory, but here we can speculate with good certainty.

The first 24 bytes are indeed the pointer to the start of an `i32` array, the length and the capacity.

The remaining 8 bytes are the `Option<i32>`. This type has 2^32 + 1 different values (2^32 Some values and 1 None value), to it needs at minimum 33 bits.
Because the i32 probably has to be aligned to a 4 byte boundary on your system, Rust uses 4 bytes to store if the `Option` is `Some` or `None`.

A bit unrelated: One thing Rust guaranties is that `Option<&i32>` has the same size as `&i32` (pointer size) because references can't be zero and we can use the 0 bitpattern to represent `None`. The same thing cannot be applied to `Option<i32>`.

Comment: Even if it was an `Option<&i32>`, it would be 8 bytes, because 8 bytes are used by the pointer. Even an `Option<i16>` would be 4 byes + 4 bytes of paddig for proper struct alignment. Likewise, an `i8` in this struct would be 1 byte + 7 bytes of padding.

Comment: @pts actually an `Option<i8>` would be two bytes (1 byte for the `i8` and 1 byte for the discriminant). Then the `Bucket` struct would contain an extra 6 bytes of padding, but those are not part of the `Option<i8>` and would not be present if the `Option<i8>` was used in a different context (e.g. in an array `[Option<i8>; 2]` there would be no extra padding between the array items).

Comment: @Jmb: Indeed, but it doesn't contradict what I wrote.

Comment: @pts sorry, I misread. I thought you meant an `Option<i8>` would be 1+7 bytes, I didn't realize you meant a _plain_ `i8`.